# jQuery animations overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several jquery animations running, each of which will need to be somewhat dependent on the success of the others. Is there a way to reliably do so without nesting each animation in another? I've looked into the 'queue' method but I believe queue is true by default? I'm running into an issue where animations start to offset one another if they're lined up like so:

```
function moduleSwap(){

                //animation 1

                //animation 2

        }

        setInterval(moduleSwap, 1000);
```

I'm using setInterval to repeat the function over and over again. Any recommendations?

Comment: can you post an example on jsfiddle plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(int) {
    if(int % 2 == 0) 
        animation_1(); 
    else
        animation_2();
}, 1000);
```

increase int through `int ++` method and pass it on `setInterval`.Its swap automatically your animations.Tricky but works for me.